# How do you remove the final space and new line in a printed statement in Python?

Tags: python

I have an assignment and part of it requires that we print a statement if the if statement we are using fails. However, we need aren't supposed to include a space or a new line after the printed statement.

```py
if second < first:
    print('Second integer can\'t be less than the first.',end='')
```

will get rid of the new line but it still says that there is a space at the end. I can not find any documentation that tells how to get rid of that final space. It prints this

```py
'Second integer can't be less than the first. '
```

with a space when it is supposed to print

```py
'Second integer can't be less than the first.'
```

without a space.

Comment: Please see [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Your posted code does not produce a trailing space.  You certainly appear to have done what is needed.

Comment: The above print statement will result in `Second integer can't be less than the first.`, there are no spaces at the end! Can you elaborate on your question?

Comment: I suspect that the console (not your application code) has added some non-printing character. What happens if you deliberately add another print statement with something easy to find at the beginning and end of, like '###'? If your code is correct, you should see output like `Second integer can't be less than the first.###`

Comment: Whenever I print, there is always a space at the end. I am using Zybooks currently to use python so it might be a problem with the console itself. If I add ### to the end, it prints as `Second integer can't be less than the first.### ` with an extra space at the end

Answer (score 1):

If you add another print statement, you will see that there is no space after the period.

```
print('Second integer can\'t be less than the first.',end='')
print ('<----')
```

Comment: If I do this, the space goes away but it still prints a new line. The final output is not supposed to have either.